# How do i update value of a key in an object inside an Array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamic list of items a user adds. I want to avoid duplicating when a user adds an item already present in the list. My list looks like

```
itemList = [ {itemId:1, name:"x", quantity:5}, {itemId:4, name:"y", quantity:2}]
```

so now if a user adds **item x** with quantity 2 i want the object with item x to update the quantity to 7 rather than adding a whole new object.
I am using find() method to get the item already present and storing it to a variable, itemObj is the item the user recently added.

```
let alrItem = state.itemList.find(
    (e) => e.itemId === itemObj.itemId
  );
let newItem = alrItem;
newItem.quantity += itemObj.quantity;
```

How do I merge this newItem to the itemList so that it just updates the quantity of that specific item?

Comment: Your code already does that. Maybe you should add a [mcve] that explains where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: If you're doing it like that, you don't need to "merge" anything, because you're mutating the same object that's already in the array. However, directly mutating state like this isn't correct, as React can't see that the array has changed (since it's the same by reference) and so you won't get a rerender.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is finding the object in the `itemList` array and then mutating the state directly. State should not be mutated directly.

Instead of using `.find()` method, use the `.map()` method to iterate over the array and update the quantity of the item that matches with the id of the new item.

```
let updatedItemList = state.itemList.map((item) => {
   if (item.itemId === itemObj.itemId) {
      return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + itemObj.quantity };
   }
   return item;
});

// update the state
setItemList(updatedItemList);
```

Note that above code will not do anything if the item isn't already present in the `itemList`. Ideally, you should also handle the case where the new item isn't already present in the `itemList`. In this case, you should just add the new item in the `itemList`.

To handle this case, all you need is a extra variable that can be used to know whether the `if` condition inside the `.map()` method evaluated to true or not.

```
let exists = false;

let updatedItemList = state.itemList.map((item) => {
   if (item.itemId === itemObj.itemId) {
      exists = true;
      return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + itemObj.quantity };
   }
   return item;
});

// if the item isn't present in the list, add it in the "updatedItemList"
if (!exists) {
   updatedItemList.push(itemObj);
}

// update the state
setItemList(updatedItemList);
```

Comment: While this is the correct approach, note that this won't update anything if the item isn't already in the list. My understanding was that in this case the OP wants to add it, with the quantity, to the list.

Comment: @RobinZigmond thank you for bringing that point to my attention. Answer updated to handle that case as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
let itemList = [ {itemId:1, name:"x", quantity:5}, {itemId:4, name:"y", quantity:2}]
let itemObj = {itemId:1, name:"x", quantity:2}

const target = itemList.find(element =>
    element.itemId === itemObj.itemId
);

if (target) {
    target.quantity = target.quantity + itemObj.quantity;
} else {
    itemList.push(itemObj);
}

console.log('itemList: ' + JSON.stringify(itemList));
```

OUTPUT:

itemList: [{"itemId":1,"name":"x","quantity":7},{"itemId":4,"name":"y","quantity":2}]